# AWS EC2 - No Space Left on Device

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance and when I log in I get

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template '/tmp/.colorlsXXX': No space left on device
```

However when I do `df -h` I see

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.2G  3.5G  55% /
devtmpfs        812M   16K  812M   1% /dev
tmpfs           828M     0  828M   0% /dev/shm
```

Doing `df -i` gives me

```
/dev/xvda1     524288 524288      0  100% /
devtmpfs       207790    414 207376    1% /dev
tmpfs          211891      1 211890    1% /dev/shm
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of `df -i`.

Comment: @EEAA updated with the output you wanted

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have exhausted all of the inodes available on your filesystem. You likely have a directory somewhere with a metric crap-ton of tiny files. You'll need to locate that directory and remove some of the files.

To search which folder of your server is eating the inode limit, you can run this command:

> find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr

Command taken from [here](https://fmartingr.com/blog/2015/05/04/amazon-ec2-no-space-left-device/)

Comment: Sure thing - a lot of people forget (or didn't even know) that inodes are a thing.

Comment: "Metric crap-ton"! ;-)

Comment: And how exactly would one find that directory?

Comment: I think you mean "metric crap-tonne".  The crap-ton is the old Imperial measure, being approximately 1.016 crap-tonnes.

Comment: @MadHatter Ha! Thank you for schooling me on these old archaic measures.

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I've seen `df -i` or inodes running out.  In my case it was a combination of loads of linux headers from old packages (`apt-get autoremove` sorted these), and multiple old copies of my own sprawling PHP website.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred to me while trying to [install *ubuntu-desktop*](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/) as instructed by AWS knowledge-center.

Then I found [here](https://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html) how to find all those directories with huge number of tiny files:

```
for i in /*; do count=`sudo find $i | wc -l`; if [ $count -gt 10000 ]; then echo $i $count; fi; done

/lib 18982
/proc 35223
/sys 36490
/usr 253941
/var 14584
```

Run it again for each suspicious sub-directory (for me it was hidden under */usr/**).

But before you remove those sub-directories with *rm -rf* (if you're absolutely sure!), try to safely remove Linux packages that were installed by other packages, but are no longer needed:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Run ***df -i*** again to see if you have more space now.

Comment: "Cryptic" directories? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: They're not hidden, either.

Comment: They're not hidden, cryptical, mysterious, etc. They're on every Linux and OSX distribution, they're extensively documented, and known to anyone with even a few hours of Linux sysadmin knowledge. (It's also the wrong answer, per OP's acceptance of the inode exhaustion explanation.)